# Accordion open next on button click

Tags: accordion, angular2-forms

Hi been searching for few days now but couldnt find anything. I have an accordion that has three accordion group, I have added a button to open the next accordion but cant seem to get it working. Can some one please help. here is what I have so far

```
<accordion [closeOthers]="true" style="margin-top:5px;">
        <accordion-group *ngFor="let registration of registrationArray; let i = index" #groupval style="margin-top:5px;" [isOpen]="registration.isAccordionOpen">
          <div accordion-heading style="width:100%;">
            Registrant No. {{i + 1}}
            <i class="pull-right float-xs-right glyphicon"
               [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': groupval?.isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-up': !groupval?.isOpen}"></i>
          </div>
          <form [formGroup]="myGroup" (ngSubmit)="gotoAddons(myDetails)">
            <div formArrayName="myDetails">
              <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
                <div style="padding-top:20px;clear:both;">
                  <div style="width:100%;background-color:#578ebe;border: 1px solid #7ca7cc;">
                    Your Address
                  </div>
                  <div style="padding-top:30px;clear:both;">
                    <div style="width:100%">
                      <div style="float:left;width:30%;text-align:right;">
                        <span class="required">*</span><label>Address Line 1</label>
                      </div>
                      <div style="float:left;width:70%;padding-left:10px;">
                        <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" id="address" name="address" formControlName="address" required>
                        <div *ngIf="myGroup.controls.myDetails.controls[i].controls.address.errors && (myGroup.controls.myDetails.controls[i].controls.address.dirty || myGroup.controls.myDetails.controls[i].controls.address.touched || submitted)" class="alert alert-danger">
                          <div [hidden]="!myGroup.controls.myDetails.controls[i].controls.address.errors.required">
                            Address Line 1 is required!
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>                
                <div style="width:100%;" *ngIf="i < registrationArray.length - 1">
                  <div style="float:right;">
                    <button (click)="groupval.isOpen = !groupval.isOpen" class="btn green">Open next tab</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:100%;"  *ngIf="i == registrationArray.length - 1" >
                  <div style="float:right;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn green">Continue</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </accordion-group>
      </accordion>
```

Removed some code for clarification. Can some one please let me know how I can open the next accordion group on the button click. Thanks in advance

Here is a working example

[plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/WDq8lU/)

stackblitz link

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-svoggg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your case I see that you're actually just closing the opened panel and that's all. Along with this you need to open a next panel which can be done by setting its `isOpen` property to true. 
A small plunkr with test implementation - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-ifmpph?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: I am getting the following error when I try to access the groups the app wont run cause of this error
Error TS2445 Property 'groups' is protected and only accessible within class 'AccordionComponent' and its subclasses. src (tsconfig project) \entrant.component.ts 262 Active

Comment: Indeed. Anyway, there's another way with similar approach - forEach on your panels array. example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-hdgjev?file=app/app.component.ts